# How do I choose an ESC for my plane motor? How do I set the current?

Tags: current, brushless-dc-motor, motor-controller, quad-copter

I made an airplane and I have to choose an ESC for the motor. This motor can operate at values ​​such as 12 V-16 C (current), 8 V-9 C, 12 V-20 C, and 8 V-12 C.

I want to run it at 8 V-12 C. Should I choose a 12 A ESC for the motor, since it can go up to 20 C, or should I choose a 20 C ESC, or is it related to the voltage of the battery I will use?

How do I set the current that the motor will draw?

Comment: C is not a unit for current.

Comment: your question belongs at https://drones.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The motor draws the current it needs. You don't set it. The maximum current is called the stall current. It is specified in the datasheet at a particular voltage.

Comment: To a great extent, you set the current by choosing the propellor.